# Update form select (dropdown) from static input field

Tags: jquery, html, forms, select

I see various ways to update a input field from a select box but how would I go about updating a select box based on the value of an input text field?

Input Text:

```
<input type="text" id="region-txt" name="region-txt" />
```

Select Box to be updated based on the input text value:

```
<select id="region" name="region">
  <option value="1">Test1</option>
  <option value="2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

Basically, I want the select box to be updated with the value of the input text field.  Using jQuery so that would be ideal.

Comment: Do you mean 'create a new option' based on the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change the selected dropdown vale you can use

```
  $('#input').keyup(function(){

    var selected = $(this).text();

    $('#region').val(selected);

    });
```

if you want to add a new option to list you can use

```
$('#input').keyup(function(){

        var selected = $(this).text();

        if($('#region option[value='+selected+']').length){
            //item already exists
        }
        else {
             $('#region').append(
                   $('<option></option>').val(selected).html("Test"+selected)
             ); 
        } 

        });
```

also can do for `change` event